# react component not re-rendering on state change from parent component firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

im trying to re-render my `header component` based off `state` from my `app parent component` (didnt include import statements)

`header.js`

```
export default class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('im inside header component');
    console.log(props);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
  }
  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }
  render() {
    if ( this.props.user ) {
      return (
        <Navbar color="light" light expand="md">
          <Link to="/"> raffleraffleraffle </Link>
          <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
          <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
            <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
              <NavItem>
                <Link to="/register">Welcome user</Link>
                <button onClick={this.props.signout}>Signout</button>
              </NavItem>
            </Nav>
          </Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      );
    }
    return (
      <Navbar color="light" light expand="md">
        <Link to="/">raffleraffleraffle</Link>
        <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
        <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
          <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
            <NavItem>
              <Link to="/register">Sign up</Link>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem>
              <Link to="/login">Sign in</Link>
            </NavItem>
          </Nav>
        </Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}
```

in my `header component` `constructor` i have 2 `console.logs` for debugging purposes.

`app.js`

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.signout = this.signout.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      user: null,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      console.log(user);
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ user })
      }
      this.setState({ user: null })
    });
  }

  signout() {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function () {
      console.log('succesfully signed out');
      this.setState({ user: null })
    }).catch(function (error) {
      // An error happened.
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Header user={this.state.user} signout={this.signout} />
          <Container fluid>
            <Route exact path="/" component={RaffleCardView} />
            <Route exact path="/raffleview" component={RaffleView} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginView} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={RegisterView} />
          </Container>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
};
export default App;
```

in my `app component constructor` im setting `this.state.user = null` in my `componentDidMount` method im setting the the `user state` whenever i get a succesful login from firebase & im also `console.log` the `user` for debugging, but i dont get the desired navbar. here is what is being `console logged` so my logic seems right. im still new to react so im not understanding the lifecycle properly thanks for all the help

[image]

Comment: Please host your code somewhere (ex: react sandbox) as that way it would be easier to debug it

Comment: my app requires firebase account, does codesandbox support that?

Comment: @AnshulSahni please read above, forgot to tag u

Comment: not sure but you can always mock network calls, you can mock write setTimeout in componentDidMount and about signout that won't be needed as of now since there is a problem only with Header not getting update

Comment: @AnshulSahni roger. does anything look wrong to you in my code tho? is this the proper way of doing things in `react`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning your user existing case in your componentDidMount. So, first it sets the state with user info then again it sets the state with null. So try like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      console.log(user);
      if (user) {
        return this.setState({ user })
      }
      this.setState({ user: null })
    });
  }
```

or you can use else block for non-existing user case without `return`. But I think it is not necessary here.